# Can functions be differentiable on sets with empty interiors?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

As a simple example, suppose we have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on the set (and taking $+\infty$ everywhere else),

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3| x_1 \in [-1, 1], x_2 \in [-1, 1], x_3 = 0\}$$

The set has no interior but a relative interior given by $(-1,1) \times (-1,1) \times \{0\}$.

Similarly, consider sets such as $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3| \langle e, x\rangle = 1, x_i \geq 0\}$, where $e$ is the one-vector. Once again, it has no interior, but has a relative interior relative to the hyperplane $\langle e, x \rangle = 1$ given by $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3| \langle e, x\rangle = 1, x_i > 0\}$,

Example functions could include:

$f(x) = \langle x, x \rangle$ for the first set

$f(x) = -\langle e, \ln(x) \rangle$ for the latter set

Are such function differentiable on such sets (i.e. the gradient exists)? If not, why? Can't seem to find any resource on this.

Edited per comment: Also, is it problematic if I were to pretend that the function was defined on the whole space, take the gradient there, and restrict it to the relative interior? For example, consider $f(x) = \langle x, x \rangle$ defined on the set $[-1, 1]^2 \times \{0\}$. What is wrong if I were to take the gradient as usual, $\nabla f(x) = 2 x$ and define it on the relative interior of the same set $(-1, 1)^2 \times \{0\}$?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.  Are you asking for a function that is defined on all of $\mathbb R^3$ (as the notation $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ indicates) but that is differentiable only on a set such as $[-1, 1]^2 \times \{0\}$, or are you looking for a definition of differentiability that works for functions defined only on $[-1, 1]^2 \times \{0\}$?

Comment: If the latter, it may be interesting to consider the notion of manifolds with boundary, of which both of your spaces are natural examples.  Here is the first Google result for me for "smooth functions on manifolds with boundary":  http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math260s10/manwithbdy.pdf .

Comment: In your second example $f(x) = -\langle e, \ln(x)\rangle$, do you mean to define $\ln(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (\ln(x_1), \ln(x_2), \ln(x_3))$?  If so, then how do you define the function on the boundary?

Comment: @LSpice In the second example, this is the sum  $-( \ln(x_1) + \ln(x_2) + \ln(x_3))$

Comment: @LSpice I guess a even lower example is whether a function, e.g., $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$ defined only for straight lines, e.g., it is only finite on the line $x_1 + x_2 = 1$ and $+infinity$ everywhere else. Is the function  differentiable on that line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which also has no interior). Is the function differentiable. in the usual sense? And if there is a compatible definition in the case it is not.

Comment: Your $x \mapsto -(\ln(x_1) + \ln(x_2) + \ln(x_3))$ is still not defined (or at least not finite) on the boundary.  Your second example definitely is not differentiable in the usual sense, because the usual definition of differentiability only handles finite functions (else how to define the difference quotient?).  I really think you don't want to view your function as defined on a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and extended by $\infty$ to all of $\mathbb R^2$; but, if you do, then you must call it $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$, not $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @LSpice Ok. I'm just going by the notation in https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/. These sets are directly taken from the book in the section about relative interiors. I just don't know how differentiability is handled. For that particular case about the boundary, I guess we could set it to be $f: 0 \mapsto 0$. But this is not the only example, another example could be $\langle x, \ln(x) \rangle$, which has the boundary condition $\langle 0, \ln(0) \rangle = 0$

Comment: Ah, if you're going by a particular book, then you'll definitely want to edit that into the question, and, if possible, refer to any specific part of the book where this question arises.  I also have no problem with the sets you mention, just with referring to functions on them as functions on the entire Euclidean space on which they live, or with functions extended by $\infty$ as valued in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I am afraid the functions you list here are not differentiable in any usual sense. You seem to be concerned with the entropy function on a simplex, as in Norman's answer below. If yes, then you should describe your specific problem; right now this question makes little sense to me.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki May I ask what doesn't make sense? As I described in the comment above a simple case is differentiability of $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$ on $x_1 + x_2 = 1$. This is sort of a yes or no answer. Yes, it is differentiable vs no it is not. LSpice has said they are not differentiable in the usual sense, and I agree with him. I don't think the answer below fully capture my concern.

Comment: @Cauchy'sCarrot: I did not mean this to be offensive. *To me*, a question "let $f$ be infinite except at a single point, is it differentiable" makes little sense if "differentiable" is understood in the usual sense, because the definition of differentiability simply makes no sense in this case. You can speak about *directional* derivatives, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the standard definition of once-differentiable manifold with boundary.

In order to define derivative, you need a normed vector space.  You need a vector space because differentiation is ${\Bbb R}$-linear.  You want to preserve the linearity because in a sense, differentiation is linearization.  You need the norm to take the limit.

The concept is generalized to manifolds by looking at the infinitesimal neighborhood of a point, the tangent space, which is a vector space.

As LSpice commented, your examples are manifolds with boundary.  The boundary is itself of a manifold one dimension lower, so you can define derivative there.

You can also consider a boundary point as part of the whole space.  There your "tangent space" is only half of a vector space.  You can generalize linearity here also, if you like.

Finally, manifolds are define by charts and you want to make sure that your differentiation operator is defined consistently across the charts.  This means that the transition maps should be differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

You can parametrize such sets and then consider the differentiability with respect to the parameters. The differentiability property will be invariant with respect to diffeomorphisms: if two parametrizations are related by a diffeomorphism (that is, by a differentiable bijection whose inverse is also differentiable), then a function differentiable with respect to one of the two parametrizations will be differentiable with respect to the other parametrization. In general, a parametrization can be any bijection. Some parametrizations may be more useful/natural than others -- e.g., parametrizations that are homeomorphisms with respect to the natural topologies would usually be better than parametrizations that are not homeomorphisms.

E.g., you can parametrize the set $S:=\{x\in\mathbb R^3\colon x_1+x_2+x_3=1,x_i>0\ \forall i\}$ by the parametrization
$$S_1\ni(s,t)\mapsto\phi(s,t):=(s,t,1-s-t)\in S$$
or, e.g., the parametrization
$$S_2\ni(s,t)\mapsto\psi(s,t):=(1-s-t,s,t)\in S,$$
where $S_1:=S_2:=\{(s,t)\in\mathbb R^2\colon s>0,t>0,s+t<1\}$. These two parametrizations are equivalent, in the sense that they are related by a diffeomorphism -- here, specifically, by the diffeomorphism
$$S_2\ni(s,t)\mapsto g(s,t):=(1-s-t,s)\in S_1$$
in the sense that $\psi=\phi\circ g$ and hence $\phi=\psi\circ g^{-1}$.

$\big($In the above example, the domains $S_1$ and $S_2$ of the two different parametrizations $\phi$ and $\psi$ of the same set $S$ were the same.
In general, though, the domains of different parametrizations of the same set may be different. Even in the above example, another parametrization of $S$ is
$$S_3\ni(s,t)\mapsto\rho(s,t):=(s,t-s,1-t)\in S,$$
where $S_3:=\{(s,t)\in\mathbb R^2\colon0<s<t<1\}\ne S_1$. The parametrization $\rho$ is then equivalent to the parametrizations $\phi$ and $\psi$.$\big)$

A function $f\colon S\to\mathbb R$ may then be called differentiable if the function $f\circ\phi\colon S_1\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable or, equivalently, if the function $f\circ\theta$ is differentiable, where $\theta$ is any parametrization of $S$ equivalent to $\phi$. Then, by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#General_rule), we also have
$$(f\circ\psi)'=(f\circ\phi\circ g)'=(f\circ\phi)'\circ g';$$
here, at each point of $S_2$, $g'$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$, and $(f\circ\phi)'$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ (that is, a linear functional).

For instance, the function $S\ni x\mapsto f(x):=x_1^2+x_2x_3$ will be differentiable, because the function $S_1\ni(s,t)\mapsto (f\circ\phi)((s,t))=s^2+t(1-s-t)$ is differentiable or, equivalently, because the function $S_2\ni(s,t)\mapsto (f\circ\psi)((s,t))=(1-s-t)^2+st[=(f\circ\phi\circ g)((s,t))]$ is differentiable.

For further reading, see e.g. [differentiation on manifolds](https://www.google.com/search?q=diffrentiation%20on%20manifolds&oq=diffrentiation%20on%20manifolds&aqs=chrome..69i57.10918j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I'm not sure this fully answers the question, because your example is of a manifold without boundary, whereas the question explicitly wants to consider differentiation on manifolds with boundary.

Comment: Is it problematic if I were to pretend that the function was defined on the entire set instead? For example, consider $f(x) = \langle x, x \rangle$ defined on the set $[-1, 1]^2 \times \{0\}$. What is wrong if I were to take the gradient as usual, $\nabla f(x) = 2 x$ and define it on the interior of the same set $(-1, 1)^2 \times \{0\}$?

Comment: With [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366738/can-functions-be-differentiable-on-sets-with-empty-interiors#comment926386_366742) choice, the functions $f : x \mapsto x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$ and $g : x \mapsto x_1^2 + x_2^2$, which agree on your given domain, would be found to have different gradients there, so that the gradient could no longer be said to be a property of the restriction of the function to $[-1, 1]^2 \times \{0\}$.

Comment: @LSpice : Concerning your first comment, you are of course right. However, I thought the main idea should be first explained on the significantly easier case of a manifold without boundary.

Comment: @Cauchy'sCarrot : As noted in the above comment by user LSpice, the gradient will not in general be a property of the restriction of the function. However, the two functions in the example given in that comment have in fact the same gradient, $(2x_1,2x_2,0)$, on the set $T:=(-1,1)^2\times\{0\}$. However, the functions $x\mapsto x_1+x_2+x_3$ and $x\mapsto x_1+x_2$ will have the same restriction to the set $T$, but their gradients, $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$, will be different (everywhere and hence) on $T$.

Comment: @LSpice : Concerning your second comment, please see my latter comment.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, right; thank you for replacing my [wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366738/can-functions-be-differentiable-on-sets-with-empty-interiors/366742#comment926391_366742) example with a [correct](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366738/can-functions-be-differentiable-on-sets-with-empty-interiors/366742#comment926420_366742) one.